# Can't resolve all parameters for Angular2Csv: (?, ?, ?)

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have followed the steps given in the link https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-csv to export to csv file in angular 4 application in ASP.Net Core but getting the error "Can't resolve all parameters for Angular2Csv: (?, ?, ?)."

Please find below the steps which i have done,

1. Have installed the angular2-csv using npm

   ```
    npm install --save angular2-csv@0.2.5
   ```
2. Then I have imported in app.module.server.ts

   ```
   import { Angular2Csv } from 'angular2-csv';
   ```

and added the providers,

```
@NgModule({
declaration:[...],
imports:[...],
providers:[Angular2Csv]
})
```

3. Then I have created the options and data for exporting to csv

   ```
   import { Angular2Csv } from 'angular2-csv';

   @Component({
       selector: 'home',
       templateUrl: './my.component.html',
       styleUrls: ['./my.component.css'],
       encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
   })
   export class MyComponent { 
   options = {
       fieldSeparator: ',',
       quoteStrings: '"',
       decimalseparator: '.',
       showLabels: false,
       headers: [],
       showTitle: true,
       title: 'asfasf',
       useBom: false,
       removeNewLines: true,
       keys: ['approved','age','name' ]
     };
     data = [
       {
         name: "Test, 1",
         age: 13,
         average: 8.2,
         approved: true,
         description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
       },
       {
         name: 'Test 2',
         age: 11,
         average: 8.2,
         approved: true,
         description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
       },
       {
         name: 'Test 3',
         age: 10,
         average: 8.2,
         approved: true,
         description: "using 'Content here, content here' "
       }
     ];
     }
   ```
4. and my template looks like this

   ```
   <angular2csv [data]="data" filename="test.csv" [options]="options"></angular2csv>
   ```

When I am building and running the solution, getting the below mentioned error

"Can't resolve all parameters for Angular2Csv: (?, ?, ?)"

Please help me in resolving this

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :

```
   downloadFile() {
   new Angular2Csv(this.data, 'test' , this.options) ;
    }
```

and call that upon a button click in your html like so

```
<a (click)="downloadFile()">Download file</a>
```

here's what I put in my options

```
this.options = {
      fieldSeparator: ';',
      quoteStrings: '"',
      decimalseparator: '.',
      showLabels: true,
      headers: ['name','age','average', 'approved','description'],
      useBom: false,
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-csv), you should just import `Angular2CsvModule`

```
import { Angular2CsvModule } from 'angular2-csv';

imports: [
  Angular2CsvModule,
  ........
],
```

And no need to provide `Angular2Csv` in your providers array. Remove that

Comment: No I have tried importing but unable to import Angular2CsvModule. My application is in angular 4. And there is a note in the docs if angular 2,4 or 5 have to use the version 0.2.5 and hence used in providers.

Answer (score 0):

### Following worked for me

#### Package.json

```
"angular2-csv": "~0.2.5",
```

#### In the component needing it, added following

```
  import { Angular2Csv } from 'angular2-csv';
```

### new Angular2Csv(...) should work then

we wish the team should have retained this without we having to add the component in the html